# Strange json deserialisation exception

Tags: c#, json

So I have a method that deserialises

```
private T Deserialize<T>(string fileName) 
{
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) 
    {
        using(var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr)) 
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this exception for some reason

> A Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartParkingApp.Models.User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Id', line 1, position 6."

what is puzzling for me is that i already executed the program succesfuly for a couple of times and this exception appeared only after i added that:

```
private void Serialize<T>(string fileName, T data) 
{
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName)) 
    {
        using(var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) 
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, data);
        }
    }
}

foreach (User el in users) 
{
    Serialize(UsersFileName, el);
}
```

so essentially i ran program with the code above once and serialisation didn't work(the file did not change, but it should have) but there were no exceptions, and when i tried to run program second time the exception appeared
Here is the json file that raises the exception:

```
    [
      {
        "CarPlateNumber": "A823BX750",
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Peter Peterson",
        "Password": "qwasdty",
        "Phone": "+79162314312"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: How are you calling `Deserialise`?

Comment: Close and re-open your file. It might have changed but your viewer is not refreshed.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, assuming you are calling `Deserialize<List<User>>` and the file contains the JSON you have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. We need more info to answer your question better.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"pathToJsonr.json";
        var d = new DeserializeClass<List<Person>>().Deserialize<List<Person>>(path);
        System.Console.WriteLine(d[0].Name);
    }
}

internal class DeserializeClass<T>
{
    internal T Deserialize<T>(string filename)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class Person
{
    public string CarPlateNumber { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
[

  {
    "CarPlateNumber": "A823BX750",
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Peter Peterson",
    "Password": "qwasdty",
    "Phone": "+79162314312"
  }
]
```

Comment: Really this is a comment, not an answer, like I already posted.

Comment: @DavidG you are correct, this much code in comments does not make sense though.

Comment: @DavidG The author of the question does not provide a complete view of his/her code. I do. In any case once he/she provides more info i will update my answer.